# How to set a hidden Text Field value based on pathname in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My Form.js having fields like below and "module" is hidden field

```
const DEFAULT_INITIAL_VALUES = Object.freeze({
module:"",
scheduledflag: false,
scheduleDateAndTime: "",
})
```

I need set value of module based on below condition

```
if(window.location.toString().indexOf("air")!=-1)
{
  //set module value to AIR
}
```

below is my TextField

```
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} shouldHide={true}>
            <TextField
              name="module"
              inputProps={
                {maxLength: 10}
              }
              label="Module"
            />
          </GridItem>
```

Is there any way I can set value of module ?

Comment: You are using Object.freeze(), you cannot change the value after freezing the object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Comment: ok thanks, is there any other way to declare and set value to hidden field?

Comment: I have added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the entire component, it's hard to know what you are looking for. You could do this in a number of ways:

Controlled component:

```js
<TextField
  name="module"
  inputProps={
  {maxLength: 10}
  }
  label="Module"
  value={window.location.toString().indexOf("air")!=-1 ? 'AIR' : ''}
  hidden
/>
```

Uncontrolled:

```js
<TextField
  name="module"
  inputProps={
  {maxLength: 10}
  }
  label="Module"
  defaultValue={window.location.toString().indexOf("air")!=-1 ? 'AIR' : ''}
  hidden
/>
```

OR

```js
const DEFAULT_INITIAL_VALUES = Object.freeze({
module: window.location.toString().indexOf("air")!=-1 ? 'AIR' : '',
scheduledflag: false,
scheduleDateAndTime: "",
})
```

In this 2nd case of uncontrolled, the `DEFAULT_INITIAL_VALUES` will need to be calculated within the scope of the component (so on each render) or you'll need to unfreeze it and do it the way you were doing it before.

Comment: Thank you:-) its worked for me -->module: window.location.toString().indexOf("air")!=-1 ? 'AIR' : '',

Comment: There is no hidden prop in MUI5 TextField https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/

Comment: This post was written 3 years ago, prior to MUI5.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the value of module key inside the object, firstly you need to use let instead of const. This will enable you to modify the object later in your code, and also remove the freeze method as it freezes the object because of which you won't be able to modify the values.

```js
let DEFAULT_INITIAL_VALUES = {
  module: "",
  scheduledFlag: false,
  scheduledDateAndTime: "",
};
```

To set values, inside if condition, set the object key this way:

```js
if(window.location.toString().indexOf("air")!=-1)
{
  //set module value to AIR
  DEFAULT_INITIAL_VALUES.module = 'AIR';
}
```

To set the value:

```js
<GridItem xs={12} sm={6} shouldHide={true}>
  <TextField
    name="module"
    inputProps={
      {maxLength: 10}
    }
    label="Module"
    defaultValue={DEFAULT_INITIAL_VALUES.module}
  />
</GridItem>
```